# Android How do i change Items in Recyclerview on scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have set up an Recyclerview with textviews and hidden buttons per row.

if the user clicks the item, the buttons are shown.

If the user clicks another item, the buttons are hidden.

The recycleview sends the position to the activity per interface which changes its property.

As long as the recyclerview is not scrolled, everything works perfectly.

Layoutmanager.getchildat(position)

Now, when items exceed the view, and the user scrolls the recyclerview, the position gets wrong. It adds up 1 per item scrolled down that the user has clicked. For Example the third Item is the first to be seen, the user clicks the fifth, the buttons are shown in the eight row.

How to fix that? Can i access a gettarget property? I tried smoothcontroller.gettargetposition and subtracted it from the position but its not the right solution.

Edit:
Just added a onViewClick(View v) to the interface and saved the viee to activity when buttons set to visible. When another view is clicked, the saved view is used to hide the buttons. (View oldView = view)

Comment: You have to understand that Recyclerview is in view layer and only displays your dataset. Accessing views directly (`Layoutmanager.getchildat(position)`) and using them to keep state (shown buttons) is violation of view holder design. You need to change your approach so items in your source data can hold "shown button" state, use `Adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)` and consume the change in `onBindViewHolder` to alter button state.

Comment: Thats obvious, but thanks for the answer. My intention is to keep a clear display of information and not bomb the screen with buttons for each row, so the row shows more when the user shows that he is interested to interact with that row. for more info/manipulate etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added a onViewClick(View v) to the interface and saved the viee to activity when buttons set to visible. When another view is clicked, the saved view is used to hide the buttons. (View oldView = view)